# Admin user allow to delete and edit other users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a problem with my users-controller. Currently, an admin user can delete itself, other users can not delete themselves. In addition, each user can edit themselves.

However, I would like an admin user to delete and edit itself and others. How i've to edit the users-conroller?

users controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy,
                                        :following, :followers]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :admin_user,     only: :destroy

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "Nutzer gelöscht"
    redirect_to users_url
  end


  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :capacity, :resource_id, :email, :password,
                                 :password_confirmation)
  end

  # Before filters

  # Confirms the correct user.
  def correct_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
  end

  # Confirms an admin user.
  def admin_user
    redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
  end
end
```

thank for the help! :)

Best regard,
Phillip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, `before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update]` prevents admin from entering edit page. Modify `correct_user` method to change this behaviour:

```
  # Confirms the correct user.
  def correct_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user) || current_user.admin?
  end
```

Comment: @PhillipLuepke you welcome. If my answer did help you please consider marking it as accepted by clicking on a checkmark on the left side of an answer